# How to change default order of Group By clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

By default data extracted by the `GROUP BY` clause is ordered as ascending.
How to change it to descending.

Answer (score 12):

You should use the derived tables on your SQL. 
For example if you want to pick up the most recent row for an specific activity you're attempt to use:

```
select * 
from activities 
group by id_customer 
order by creation_date
```

but it doesn't work. Try instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( select * 
       from activities 
       order by creation_date desc ) sorted_list 
GROUP BY id_customer
```

Answer (score 9):

Add `DESC` to the `GROUP BY` clause, e.g. :

```
GROUP BY myDate DESC
```

Answer (score 8):

As the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) says,

```
SELECT * FROM foo GROUP BY bar
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM foo GROUP BY bar ORDER BY bar
```

Default behaviour can not be changed, but you can use

```
SELECT * FROM foo GROUP BY bar ORDER BY bar DESC
```

without experiencing any speed penalties as the sorting will be performed on the grouped field anyway. 
By the way, when sorting is not important you can get (small) speed-up by using ORDER BY NULL.

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY foo DESC`?